# Android special layout

Tags: android, imageview

I need to create a layout in Android like the image below:
The red rectange is the viewport. it should be possible to zoom in and pan until the borders of the image that contains the 4 imageviews.

I've tried putting the images in a gridview, that didn't really work
After that i tried putting them in a tablelayout, but the images have to keep aspect ratio.
so each row in the tablelayout had the correct width but the height was only half the rowview.
So when i pan it's possible to see the white edges from the rowview that was not filled completely

[image]

What would be the best way to achieve this layout?

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problems have you encountered? Beyond that, the red rectangle is a "viewport" on *what*?

Comment: the red rectangle contains whats visible on the screen

Comment: within the rectange you can see the images

Comment: Did you figure this out? i'm trying the same thing and cant figure it out!